# What are the steps to implement Adobe Analytics in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am new to Adobe Analytics. I have installed required platform specific packages , registered the ACPCore in mainactivity and appdelegate. I am calling TrackState and TrackAction methods in ACPCore. Is it required to call LifeCycle codes as well? Because we are unable to see test events logged in Adobe Analytics console.

Comment: You could check https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/tree/master/sdks/Xamarin .

Comment: Adobe Analytics is right now in its baby steps stage and hence cannot track screens as of now, but very soon will be able to. It is necessary to register all the extensions like UserProfile,Signal, Identity etc and do the code for LifeCycle tracking and put LogLevel as Verbose to track app launches. I am yet to verify if my App launches are getting logged in the Adobe console, will definitely update here.